# Can the clone brush sample surfaces facing away from the camera?

Tags: texture-baking, texture-painting

I am touching up some textures on a high poly mesh from a 3D scanned truck.  The truck tire on the left side is missing color information, therefore I would like to clone the color information from the right side tire.

The problem is when I start painting onto the new tire, it doesn't sample the surface of the other side of the truck. Rather, it samples the same side of the truck simply because it's what you see in the viewport.

Is there a way to make the clone brush sample from the other side of a mesh, even when the camera isn't pointing directly at it?

If not, can anyone recommend a good workaround? I thought about doing a screen capture of the colored tire from a straight angle, then using that image to paint onto the other tire, but that seems kind of hacky.  I also thought about duplicating the colored tire and boolean-ing it in place of the non-colored tire. I also considered re-baking the uv-map and then taking it into GIMP/photoshop, but this is very arduous since the UV map from the scan is extremely arbitrary, not to mention it's a .OBJ with like 600k triangles.

Thanks in advance for any feedback you guys can give me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to clone from a surface directly behind the brush, then no, this isn't supported.

However, if its slightly offset - you can do something like this using hidden faces.

- disable **back-face culling** in the project paint options panel.
- enable face-masking in the header (MKey)
- select faces on the clone *source*, then Hide with HKey.
- select faces to paint onto
  *(note that border select works well in both cases)*.
- paint...

---

Another option would be to duplicate the geometry in editmode and move it so it can be used as a clone-source, though this is isn't very convenient.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried this but unfortunately the clone brush still samples from the side of the mesh that is in view, rather than the other side of the mesh which is not in view.  Perhaps the limitation here is that if there are multiple surfaces in the way, then blender assumes that the correct sampling area is the surface that is in view?

Comment: Ah, my bad - edited answer.

Comment: Thanks again. I hadn't thought about duplicating the geometry and rotating it around.  While somewhat inconvenient, it is at least a workaround that is quicker than the other methods I was considering!  I'll give the face-masking technique a try too.